# Synchronizing package databases

Tags: docker, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I wrote Dockerfile:

```
FROM base/archlinux
RUN pacman -Syu
```

When Docker runs second step: `RUN -Syu`

I see something like this:

::Synchronizing package databases...

error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from mirror.leaseweb.net : Resolving timed out after 10000 miliseconds

etc...

Is something wrong with base/archlinux? [link to hub.docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/base/archlinux/)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your concrete question; no I do not think there is something wrong with the version of base/archlinux I am using (imageId 12e0bd421505).  I ran the exact same Dockerfile and it works until the question `Proceed with installation? [Y/n]`. I think it expects manual input there, and it fails...

Can you make sure that from the machine where you're building from, that mirror.leaseweb.net is accessible?

Comment: So; my conclusion so far: the code you mentioned works fine from my machine, you seem to have the proper connectivity... Maybe you could retry it... Otherwise I would not really know.